# Why do photos look blurry in Aperture but sharp in Mac OS X Finder?

Tags: apple-aperture, sharpening, macbook

I see a strange behaviour in Apple's Aperture (latest version).

When I import pictures taken by a Samsung NX1000 into Aperture and open a pic, at first it looks sharp — but after less than a second, the picture becomes blurry.

If I open the original pic from the camera through Mac Finder, the picture looks sharp.

Does it have something to do that Aperture does not recognize my lens, a 20-50mm F3.5-5.6 ED II?

I see that the camera model is correct but the lens is listed as "Unknown Lens".

Attached are a picture opened in Aperture (left), and the same pic opened from the Finder. The picture on the right is much better. How is this possible? I just import the pic without any editing into Aperture and it turns this way.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [RAWs looking massively different in Aperture/Mac OS Preview compared to camera preview and (Canon) PictureStyleEditor](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30368/raws-looking-massively-different-in-aperture-mac-os-preview-compared-to-camera-p)

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/how-can-different-raw-converter-programs-give-different-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably working with RAW files.  RAW files include a preview of the image rendered as the camera would have made a JPEG, which includes some sharpening applied.  When you first load the image in a program like aperture, the preview JPEG is displayed until the RAW file can be processed.  Since the RAW file has no sharpening applied, it appears to get more blurry after processing finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My camera settings say JPEG but I just discovered that a firmware update is available what should fix several bugs.