# Why does the same raw image look different in Rawtherapee than in geeqie & DSLR preview and how to get the same preview as geeqie

Tags: raw, rawtherapee

[image: Left image is opened on geeqie and on right hand side image is opened with rawtherapee]

On left side of this image it shows the raw image opened with geeqie and on right hand side same raw image opened with rawtherapee. Geeqie showed me exactly the same way as I see in the DSLR preview after capturing the image but rawtherapee shows me brightened picture. Can you please help what's happening here and how can see the same image as I see in preview of camera and geeqie?

I got into new trouble, now my image looks so dark, I know there is problem with my settings, can someone please help me understand what's happening here?
[image: Now every image opened in raw therapee becomes dark]
Note: Both are same raw images opened in different applications.

Comment: related (but not duplicate) question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/how-can-i-reproduce-the-camera-internal-postprocessing

Comment: Can't see from the screenshot, but in RawTherapee what is the Exposure Compensation slider set to? Try turning that down a bit. Also, that's a fairly old version of RawTherapee, you could update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can different RAW converter programs give different results?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/how-can-different-raw-converter-programs-give-different-results)

Comment: @vclaw I tried various exposure compensation but still could not get the same preview as geeqie. With exposure compensation 0.0 the whiteness in the image is reduced but still way different from geeqie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like rawtherapee is showing you the RAW image with a very flat base curve

When a program displays a RAW image, it must map the full range of pixel values storable in the 16-bit raw to the lower bit levels (typically 8-bit) which can be handled by your computer and screen. It doesn't necessarily do this with a linear transformation, it will apply a "base curve" (sometimes called something different).

In your case, it looks like RawTherapee is using a different base curve to the other applications, I'm not familiar with RawTherapee but most raw applications will have default base curves for different camera models - it might be that it doesn't have a default for your model of camera.

In the specific case of geeqie it is not applying a base curve itself, it is using the embedded preview image that your camera writes into the RAW file - which explains why it looks exactly the same as the preview on your DSLR.

Comment: The other half of the answer is that geeqie is simply showing you the camera-generated embedded preview image from the RAW file, it doesn't actually do any processing of the RAW data.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle - I wasn't familiar enough with geeqie to comment on it's behaviour, but I assumed that might be a possibility. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> how can see the same image as I see in preview of camera and geeqie?

By using the software that came with your camera to convert the raw file. Only this way will you be able to get the proprietary raw conversion that's happening in your camera (or at least very close to that).

Answer (score 1):

Don't threat image from RAW file as a "photo". Everything is subjective and there is not one good representation of RAW image. Every device or software has its own way to process them into bitmap.

You could create preset in Rawtherapee to make it as much similar as in another software and make it loaded default when loading RAW file