# Image artefacts when exporting RAW to JPEG

Tags: raw, jpeg, artifacts, export

I have a bunch of pictures in RAW format (.CR2) taken with a Canon EOS 1100D.

When I view these files using Windows Photos app the images look great, however when exporting to JPEG using RawTherapee or Adobe Lightroom the quality is much worse then I expected.

The colors are much different and there are some artifacts on the edges where the different colors meet.

I've also tried exporting to PNG thinking it is the JPEG compression that's causing these issues but it has the same artifacts as the JPEG export.

Here's a screenshot from the RAW preview in Windows:

[image: RAW image in Windows Photo app]

And here's the exported file:

[image: Exported JPEG]

Any help with solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are many previous questions about why an exported RAW photo is different than the preview. Did you see those already? https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30368/9161 and https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8707/9161 for example?

Comment: To those voting to close: I don't think this is a mere problem of color response from the demosaicing app.

Comment: Are the pictures shown a crop of the full size picture or a scaled down version? What is the scale of the light lines in the actual photo? A couple of pixels or much wider? These look like demosaicing artifacts. Some apps have a choice of demosaicing algorithms, and some may give different results here.

Comment: What color profile are you using for your output image? sRGB is standard for most image viewers.

Comment: Related: [While shooting in RAW, do you have to post-process it to make the picture look good?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76351/15871) and [Opening NEF files on windows initially open fine but then change contrast](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104573/15871)

Answer (score 1):

When previewing the images in windows photos you are probably viewing the embedded jpeg images with default camera processing applied. If you used Canon's software, that can apply the camera's jpeg settings to the raw file, I suspect you would have much more consistent results.